# How can I get the URL to view an individual FormResponse for an admin?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

As the creator of a Google Form, when I view it, I can click on "Responses" then "Individual" and see the individual responses. As I page through them, the value of the `response` URL fragment updates:

`.../edit#response=ACYDBNhz7KqAa1gqe-3nDNioHG0ojRS8LhPMFn6EDLDWbx8hjbfA6qc79YYIJu`

I can use that URL to link to a specific response.

I have a script attached to the form with an `onFormSubmit` function. When I get the `response` from the [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3) and I get it's ID with [`getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getid), that ID does not match the ID in the URL for that response. That is, if I put that ID in as the value of the `response` fragment in the above URL, it does not link to that response.

Why does the FormResponse ID not match the ID used in the fragment? Is there a way to get one that works? I don't want [`getEditResponseUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#geteditresponseurl). I want the URL to *view* the response as an admin.

Comment: Have you tried `getSummaryUrl()` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getSummaryUrl())?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @TiffanyG.Wilson. Tried it out but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try to get the edit Url of a response and check for the unique parameter. May be that matches to the response parameter given in above url.

Comment: Good idea @WaqarAhmad but I tried that and they don't match unfortunately.

Comment: Then I'll recommend to build your own webapp and pass the reponse Id as webapp URL parameter. Apps Script will receive the reponse Id, then look for the that reponse and return it in webapp.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @WaqarAhmad. Guess that's what you'd have to do. More involved than what I care to implement for now.

Comment: @JeffBowen did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Riccardo Sorry, never did. Moved on from this project.